# How to prevent `scalike` from converting `LocalDateTime` to a specific LocalDateTime

Tags: scala, jdbc, scalikejdbc

I am using `scalike` as a simple sql connector.

To retrieve `sql.timestamp` to `LocalDateTime` we use `wrappedResultSet.localDateTime(1)`.

Unfortunately, it does add an offset (+1 in my case).

By digging the scalike code, I have seen this is a "feature":

```
implicit def javaTimeLocalDateTime(implicit z: OverwrittenZoneId): TypeBinder[LocalDateTime] =
    Binders.sqlTimestamp.map(Binders.convertJavaTimeLocalDateTime(z.value))
```

How could I convert `sql.timestamp` to `LocalDateTime` without adding any offset ?

I already tried by overloading the `z` value without success

```
implicit val z: OverwrittenZoneId = OverwrittenZoneId(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
```

Comment: As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. So there is no need to use legacy classes like `java.sql.Timestamp`. Has your *scalike* tool not yet been updated to support *java.time*?

Comment: @BasilBourque, I ll have a look at it, thanks

Comment: We use scalike with `java.time.OffsetDateTime` directly, so maybe you could use that and specify the offset you want?